# Setup gocd on linux, but the jobs are all "waiting for agent"

Tags: continuous-integration, go-cd

I setup GoCD on an Ubuntu box and followed the instructions to create additional agents on that host.

The agents tab shows six agents, all enabled, all idle. One has the resource 'data' because I want to make sure some checked out artifacts go in a consistent place. The remaining five agents show "none specified" for resources or environments.

The Admin/environments page shows "no environments have been setup".

I've configured YAML descriptions of the jobs to be pulled from a repo. That works.

If I navigate through the "Config Repositories" pages and inspect the builds, there are no Resource listed on the job settings page.

And yet the pipelines are all just stuck "Waiting for an agent". Descriptions of this problem seem to imply that it's only caused by resources or agents, but I don't believe that's the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'd gone to the trouble of setting up "pipelines as code", I decided it would be easy enough to just start over (if at first you don't succeed, power cycle the device). I uninstalled the server and the agent, sorted out how to remove all the additional agents, and reinstalled everything.

Now it seems to be working.

My best guess is that somewhere in the server or agent, one of my various experiments with using resources had caused something to become confused.

It does not inspire confidence. :-(